Samsung Book2 Pro 360 + Ubuntu 23.10 Speakers are not working
I'm totally new with Linux, but I would like to learn so I installed Ubuntu 23.10. All was good until I noticed that the speakers were not functional.
After a lot of googling and trying many weird commands, I noticed the dump info from one of them could be relevant. Please pay attention to the bold text:
$ journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"
abr 14 10:10:27 tutubuntu kernel: software IO TLB: area num 16.
abr 14 10:10:27 tutubuntu kernel: pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
abr 14 10:10:27 tutubuntu kernel: PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
abr 14 10:10:27 tutubuntu kernel: software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x0000000048b90000-0x000000004cb90000] (64MB)
abr 14 10:10:27 tutubuntu kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011: a92902398e16c49778cd90f99e4f9ae17c55af53'
abr 14 10:10:27 tutubuntu kernel: integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011: 13adbf4309bd82709c8cd54f316ed522988a1bd4'  
abr 14 10:10:28 tutubuntu kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100  
abr 14 10:10:28 tutubuntu kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
abr 14 10:10:28 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
abr 14 10:10:28 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
abr 14 10:10:28 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
abr 14 10:10:28 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
abr 14 10:10:29 tutubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1713082229.015:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/opt/microsoft/msedge/msedge" pid=656 comm="apparmor_parser"
abr 14 10:10:29 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 2
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: autoconfig **for ALC298:** line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    **speaker_outs=0** (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    inputs:
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:      Mic=0x18
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: hda_dsp_hdmi_build_controls: no PCM in topology for HDMI converter 3
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input33
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input34
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input35
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input36
abr 14 10:10:30 tutubuntu kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input37

Note: "autoconfig for ALC289" says "speaker_outputs=0"
Is this something that is easy to fix?
